# Reduce space in TOC between section groups

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I have the following TOC:

> section 1
>   subsection 1.1 ...................... 2
>
> section 2 
>   subsection 2.1 ...................... 2

How can i reduce the spacing between the first 'group' of items related to section 1 and between the second 'group' of items related to section 2?

I know how to decrease the spacing between items of *the same* group, e.g., between all subsections of section 2.

I've seen similar posts but i couldn't apply the provided solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is defined as part of the function that sets the `\section` heading in the ToC, known as `\l@section`. Here's its definition inside [`article.cls`](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls?view=co):

```
\newcommand*\l@section[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

Note the use of `\addvspace{<space>}` which inserts a vertical gap *up to* the `<space>` provided. You can change (or remove) this using the following [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
  {\addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}

\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsection{Another subsection}

\end{document}
```

---

The same can be achieved using [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft):

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt}
```

Comment: great, the tocloft thing works (and it's actually neat and concise)!